# ¿Cómo agregar dinamicamente delegados Action a un array mediante reflexión?

Tags: c#

Bueno pego mi codigo y explico lo que intento hacer:

```
public class EntityRecetario
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Abre coneccion a la base de datos.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    
    // Este este es el array por el cual quiero ir dinamicamente agregando los action que estan mas abajo, pero para ello los quiero ir agregando con reflexión.
    static Action<object>[] LstActions; // Coleccion command delegados

    static EntityRecetario() 
    {
        // Quiero hacer esto pero dinamicamente mediante reflexión.
        //LstActions = new Action<object>[13]
        //{
        //    cmdConsultaReceta,
        //    cmdUpDateReceta,
        //    cmdDeleteReceta,
        //    cmdNewReceta,
        //    cmdConsultaRecetaIngrediente,
        //    cmdUpDateIngrediente,
        //    cmdDeleteIngrediente,
        //    cmdNewIngrediente,
        //    cmdConsultaIngrediente,
        //    cmdUpDateProveedor,
        //    cmdDeleteProveedor,
        //    cmdNewProveedor,
        //    cmdConsultaProveedor
        //};
        
        // y aca es lo que estoy intentando pero no doy con la tecla no se como agregar el 
        //delegado action meidnate la reflexión al array:

        LstActions = new Action<object>[0];

        Type propertyInfo = typeof(EntityRecetario);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (FieldInfo F in propertyInfo.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)) // Aqui ocurre la magia :)
        {
            // Aca busco todos los nombre que sean Action.
            if (F.FieldType.Name.Substring(0, 6) == typeof(Action).Name & F.Name != "LstActions")
            {
                i++;
                Array.Resize(ref LstActions, LstActions.Length + i);
                LstActions[i] = ? ;
            }
        }
    }

    #region --///-- Section of commandos actions delegate --///--

    private static Action<object> cmdConsultaReceta = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdUpDateReceta = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdDeleteReceta = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdNewReceta = async (Parameter) =>
    {
       //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdConsultaRecetaIngrediente = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdUpDateIngrediente = async (Parameter) =>
    {
       //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdDeleteIngrediente = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdNewIngrediente = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdConsultaIngrediente = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdUpDateProveedor = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdDeleteProveedor = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdNewProveedor = async (Parameter) =>
    {
        //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    private static Action<object> cmdConsultaProveedor = async (Parameter) =>
    {
       //Codigo a ejecutar.....
    };

    #endregion --///--- 
}
}
```

Bueno la idea es dinámicamente agregar los action mediante reflexión al array, entonces solo tendré que agregar el delegado mas abajo y luego dinámicamente se agregara al array.

Bueno extiendo mas la explicación.

```
 public static void EjecutCommand(CommandName commandName, object parameter)
    {
       LstActions[((int)commandName)].Invoke(parameter);
    }

siendo CommandName una clase enum:
[Flags]
    public enum CommandName
    {
        cmdConsultaReceta,
        cmdUpDateReceta,
        cmdDeleteReceta,
        cmdNewReceta,
        cmdConsultaRecetaIngrediente,
        cmdUpDateIngrediente,
        cmdDeleteIngrediente,
        cmdNewIngrediente,
        cmdConsultaIngrediente,
        cmdUpDateProveedor,
        cmdDeleteProveedor,
        cmdNewProveedor,
        cmdConsultaProveedor,
    }
```

en esta (clase enum) cargo los nombres de los metodos action que voy agregando para los pueda seleccionar en el metodo (EjecutCommand) y ejecutar.
el codigo anda re bien no tengo ningun problema, pero lo que quiero lograr es cargar el array dinamicamente sin tener yo que agregar el delegado action al momento de agregarlo al codigo. Lo que digo es agrego el metodo action y este dinamicamente se añade al array listo y me olvido, bueno luego tendre que añadir el nombre del metodo al enum, pero eso no es problema.

Comment: Y cuál es el resultado? Cuál es el resultado esperado? Cuál es el error?

Comment: Por qué estás utilizando `GetFields()` en lugar de `GetMethods()`? Has dado una ojeada a la documentación de [Reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Hola que tal Arriel, lo que busco con esto es que el array se cargue solo (dinamicamente) con reflexión, ¿y esto para que? para que solo tenga que ir agregando a medida que precise metodos action.